# How to delete a line spacing in csv file using java

Tags: java, csv

```
Link<String> s = new ArrayList();
s = func();//this function returns a list of strings each of which will be in the //form of CREATE,i,j,k 

FileWriter ff = new FileWriter(fname,false);
for(String d:s)
{
ff.append(d);
}
```

When I used the above code Each string(i.e, record like CREATE,i,j,k  is not  placed in new line
But when i use

```
ff.append(d+"\n")
```

I am getting a line spaccing between each line.
So how to remove the line spacing or how to insert each record into new line without any line spacing

Answer (score 1):

```
Link<String> s = new ArrayList();
s = func();//this function returns a list of strings each of which will be in the //form of CREATE,i,j,k 

try (PrintWriter ff = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fname,false));)
{
  for(String d:s)
  {
      // print without line feed
      ff.print(d);
      // print with line feed
      ff.println(d);
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to write it into csv file

Comment: Please be more specific: What's the difference between line spacing and new line in your case? Maybe also post a part of your output file and tell us what's wrong with it.